# Show that there is a polynomial of degree at most $2n-1$ for which $f(x_i) = a_i$ and $f'(x_i) = b_i$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, numerical-methods

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n$ real numbers and $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be distinct real numbers. Show that there is a polynomial of degree at most $2n-1$ for which $f(x_i) = a_i$ and $f'(x_i) = b_i.$

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683484/show-that-there-is-a-polynomial-of-degree-at-most-n-1-for-which-fx-i-a-i?noredirect=1#1683489). I think we can use the same Lagrangian interpolation idea here. But I don't know how to adjust for the fact that $f'(x_i) = b_i$.

Comment: You can indeed use the same kind of trick. Try to construct two families of polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_n$ and $q_1,\cdots q_n$ in such a way that $p_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$, $p'_i(x_j)=0$, $q_i(x_j)=0$ and $q'_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: But we need the same function right?

Comment: By the way, this can also be done in a non-constructive way if you interpret it as an isomorphism between the space of polynomials of degree at most $2n-1$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: once you have those polynomials you can just take a linear combination of them to get your $f$ (as in one of the answer to your first question).

Comment: Any ideas how to construct this $q_i(x_j)$?

Comment: It seems you have to add in your question $b_1,b_2,.....,b_n$

Answer (score 1):

For $i\in\{1,..,n\}$ let
\begin{gather}
u_i(x)=\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^n\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j},
\end{gather}

then for $j\in\{1,..,n\}$
\begin{gather}
u_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}.
\end{gather}

Now let

\begin{gather}
p_i(x)=u_i(x)^2*(2u_i'(x_i)(x_i-x)+1)
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
q_i(x)=u_i(x)^2*(x-x_i)
\end{gather}

Then by the product and chain rule we have
\begin{gather}
p_i'(x)=2u_i'(x)u_i(x)*(2u_i'(x_i)(x_i-x)+1)-u_i(x)^2*2u_i'(x_i) 
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
q_i'(x)=u_i(x)^2+2u_i(x)u_i'(x)(x-x_i) 
\end{gather}

and we see
\begin{gather}
p_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij},\
q_i(x_j)=0,\
p_i'(x_j)=0,\
q_i'(x_j)=\delta_{ij}
\end{gather}

Now
\begin{gather}
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_ip_i(x)+b_iq_i(x)
\end{gather}

is a polynomial of degree at most $2n-1$ which has the desired properties.

Comment: Excellent proof. I am close to it but can not find the exact function.